# Eclipse atalhos

Tags: eclipse

primeira vez que pergunto aqui e não sei se é o foco e se podem banir minha pergunta.
Mas gostaria de saber sobre atalhos do Eclipse como por exemplo encontrar um método em um projeto grande sem ir de classe em classe

Comment: Bom, espero que te ajude, dê uma olhada nos links abaixo: https://www.devmedia.com.br/principais-atalhos-do-eclipse/25614 https://blog.algaworks.com/atalhos-e-configuracoes-para-ganhar-produtividade-com-eclipse/ https://medium.com/sienge-produto-e-tecnologia/alguns-atalhos-do-eclipse-65ad47eec6ae

Comment: `Ctrl + O` mostra a lista de métodos da classe.